# Serialize field is 'nil' but fails a 'IS NULL' query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a serialized field in my `Project` model called rankings.

```
serialize :rankings
```

Here are some queries with results:

```
@projects = Project.where("rankings IS NULL")         -> 0 results
@projects = Project.where("rankings = ?", "")         -> 0 results
@projects = Project.where("rankings = ?", {})         -> 0 results    
@projects = Project.where("rankings = ?", "{}")       -> 0 results
@projects = Project.where("rankings = ?", {}.to_yaml) -> 0 results

Project.find(275).rankings -> nil
```

This is for a table with 100s of nils (of which #275 is one). What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure the rankings column is null ? Check your database column natively ?

Comment: try this: Project.where("rankings = ?", {}.to_yaml)

Comment: Are the entries for `rankings` actually NULL or are they blank strings? They're not the same thing.

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev This also returns 0 results.

Comment: @mbratch I tried doing `Project.all.sample.rankings` in console and it gave me a `nil`. They appear to be actually NULL.

Comment: @ThongKuah From console, I'm getting `nil`s from direct queries, as I've updated in my question above. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: @XavierHolt is probably on the right track here with their answer. What I meant to ask is for you to check it via the mysql console or postgres (whatever database you are using) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer.

#### To query for nil with a serialized field in Rails, you have to do:

```
@projects = Project.where("rankings = ?", nil.to_yaml)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class), Rails serializes things with YAML.  Playing around with this shows that the results aren't necessarily what you'd expect:

```
irb(main):007:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):008:0> nil.to_yaml
=> "--- \n...\n"
irb(main):009:0> {}.to_yaml
=> "--- {}\n"
```

I can't say for sure that this is what you're running into, but it seems like a decent place to start.  Hope it helps!

**PS:**  I'm going to guess that using the hash form of `where` will generate the right query:

```
@projects = Project.where(:rankings => nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 with Postgres, Rails seems to populate an actually string of "null" for serialized columns that are nil.

That is, Rails makes the field appear to be `nil` but you have to specifically query for "null" to get the right result.

So under Rails 4, the accepted answer no longer works, but this works for me:

```
@projects = Project.where("rankings = 'null'")
```